# Linear regression of an unnamed column using pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots

How can I calculate the linear regression of a column without a name?
I have a file called lindat.csv looking something like this:

```
1,2
2,4
3,6
4,8
```

I tried doing this, but the index part doesn't seem to work inside the regression.

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel={X axis},
    ylabel={Y axis}
   ]
   \addplot [black, thin, dashed]
   table [
     x index=0,
     y={create col/linear regression={y= index=1}},
     col sep=comma]
    {data/lindat.csv};

   \addplot [only marks]
   table [,
     x index=0,y index=1
     col sep=comma
    ]
    {data/lindat.csv};

  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \caption{}
 \label{fig:graph1}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel={X axis},
    ylabel={Y axis}
    ]
    \addplot [black, thin, dashed]
    table [
    x index=0,
    y={create col/linear regression},
    col sep=comma]
    {data/lindat.csv};

    \addplot [only marks]
    table [,
    x index=0,y index=1,
    col sep=comma
    ]
    {data/lindat.csv};

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

More generally, to select any column by its index, you can use `y={create col/linear regression={y=[index]#}` where `#` is the index.

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel={X axis},
    ylabel={Y axis}
    ]
    \addplot [black, thin, dashed]
    table [
    x index=0,
    y={create col/linear regression={y=[index]1}},
    col sep=comma]
    {data/lindat.csv};

    \addplot [only marks]
    table [,
    x index=0,y index=1,
    col sep=comma
    ]
    {data/lindat.csv};

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```